# No exception for incorrectly configured WCF server hostname

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have a server client implementation using `WCF` where the clients sends a `Connect` message to the server when it starts.

This is the code I'm using in my client application (WCF service is self hosted in this case):

```
public void InitializeCommunicationChannel()
    {
        this._proxy = new DistributionServiceClient(this._context, "NetTcpBinding_IDistributionService");

        Log.Write(Level.Debug, "Initialized proxy..");

        //set credentials
        this._proxy.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Domain = PasswordManager.ServerAdminDomain;
        this._proxy.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = PasswordManager.ServerAdminUsername;
        this._proxy.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = PasswordManager.ServerAdminPassword;

        this._proxy.InnerChannel.Faulted += new EventHandler(this.InnerChannel_Faulted);
        this._proxy.InnerChannel.Closing += new EventHandler(this.InnerChannel_Closing);

        //send a connect message to the server
        try
        {
            Log.Write(Level.Debug, "Sending connect message..");

            this.StationId = this._proxy.ClientConnected(ClientConfiguration.HostName, this.Version, ClientConfiguration.CurrentIpAddress);
            Log.Write(Level.Debug, "Connect message sent..");

            Log.Write(Level.Info, "Connected to server.");
            this.ConnectionState = "Connected";
        }
        catch (ConfigurationErrorsException cEx)
        {
            Log.Write(Level.Error, cEx.Message);
            Log.Write(Level.Debug, cEx.ToString());
        }
        catch (FaultException fEx)
        {
            //probably server didn't recognize configured ip or hostname
            Log.Write(Level.Error, fEx.Message);
            Log.Write(Level.Debug, fEx.ToString());
        }
        catch (CommunicationException cEx)
        {
            Log.Write(Level.Debug, cEx.Message);
            Log.Write(Level.Debug, cEx.ToString());
        }
        catch (System.Security.Authentication.InvalidCredentialException iEx)
        {
            Log.Write(Level.Error, iEx.Message);
            Log.Write(Level.Debug, iEx.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Write(Level.Error, ex.Message);
            Log.Write(Level.Debug, ex.ToString());
        }

    void InnerChannel_Closing(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Log.Write(Level.Debug, "Communication channel is closing down..");
        this.ConnectionState = "Attempting connection..";
    }

    void InnerChannel_Faulted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.ConnectionState = "Not connected";
        Log.Write(Level.Debug, "Communication channel faulted..");

        //something went wrong
        this._proxy.Abort();
        this._proxy.InnerChannel.Faulted -= this.InnerChannel_Faulted;
        this._proxy.InnerChannel.Closing -= this.InnerChannel_Closing;

        //give the server a chance to get back online; retry after 10s
        Thread.Sleep(10000);

        //re-initialize the communication channel
        this.InitializeCommunicationChannel();
    }
```

The problem that I'm having is that when the server address is not correctly configured in the client's config file, the channel faults when I try to send the `Connect` message, but no exception is being caught.

Is this because the connection is occurring on a different thread therefore it never ends up in my `catch` code? How do I catch endpoint configuration exceptions in code? The `InnerChannel_Faulted`'s `EventArgs` member doesn't contain any useful information.

Thanks a lot.